# binding.gyp doesn't see included library

Tags: node-gyp

I'm playing around with [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) and I am trying to add a library, `muParser` to some of the example code by adding a folder `libraries` at the same level as `hello.cc` and simply adding `#include <muParser.h>` to `hello.cc`.

`libraries` has the following structure:

`-include - with files such as muParser.h`

`-lib - with a single file libmuparser.a`

The problem is that my `binding.gyp` file doesn't do what I think it should as for the following 2 variants, relative and absolute paths, I get the same error - `../hello.cc:3:10: fatal error: 'muParser.h' file not found` when I `npm install`:

```
{
"targets": [
{
  "target_name": "hello",
  "sources": [ "hello.cc" ],
  "include_dirs": [
    "../libraries/include/"
  ],
  "libraries": [
    "-llibmuparser', '-L../libraries/lib/"
  ],
}
 ]
}

{
"targets": [
{
  "target_name": "hello",
  "sources": [ "hello.cc" ],
  "include_dirs": [
    "<(module_root_dir)/../libraries/include/"
  ],
  "libraries": [
    "<(module_root_dir)/../libraries/lib/libmuparser.a"
  ],
}
]
}
```

Can anybody explain how I include this library?

Answer (score 0):

I create **binding.gyp** file manually under the path C:\Users\Administrator with following content:

```
{
"targets": [
{
"target_name": "binding",
"sources": [ "build/Release/binding.node" ]
}
]
}
```

After that, I run **node-gyp rebuild** command and the issue is solved.

Comment: send the screenshot of when showing  error npm install

Comment: Sorry but running `node-gyp rebuild` gives the same error.